# fecha en español con carbon en laravel

Tags: laravel, carbon

hola estoy trabajando con laravel y carbon, tengo el siguiente codigo en mi controlador:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        Carbon::setlocale('es');
        Carbon::setUTF8(true);
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
    }
```

y en mi vista:

```
 <td>{{ $usuario->created_at->formatLocalized('%B') }}</td>
```

y me imprime el mes en ingles, lo quiero en español, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?, saludos.

Comment: Intenta poner la configuración en el método del controlador que devuelve la vista y no en el constructor: `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
 Carbon::setLocale('es');`

Comment: intentare, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debería bastar con realizar lo siguiente:

- Ve a la ruta: **`tuapp/config/app.php`**

Ubica la línea: **`83`** que contiene lo siguiente:

```
'locale' => 'en',
```

Esta parte es la que cambiaremos a español, colocando el sigueinte valor:

```
'locale' => 'es',
```

De modo que si ahora obtengo la fecha y accedo al nombre del mes así:

```
$fecha = now()->monthName;
```

Tendremos una salida como esta:

> diciembre

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo no se si esto te funcione creo que podría, es la forma mas fácil:

```
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
$fecha = Carbon::parse($inputs['Fecha']);
$mes = $meses[($fecha->format('n')) - 1];
$inputs['Fecha'] = $fecha->format('d') . ' de ' . $mes . ' de ' . $fecha->format('Y');
```